# Is it possible to get a "live" version of the last modified date of a google drive file?

Tags: google-drive-api, modified-date

I've noticed that when i open a file in google drive and modify an element and ask for the last modified date it gives me the actual time and date of the modification, while if i keep the file open and then make changes for the second time and ask for the modified date, the date and time remains stuck to the first modification date for about two minutes.

I was wondering if there's a way to get the actual "live" modified date of a google drive file using python's API or if anyone knows another method/program language where it's possible to get this information "live".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. The granularity of Drive updates isn't something you can influence and there is only a single API property that you can fetch.

Comment: could there be a way to trigger a sync file in the cloud?

Comment: you could register for file changes using the drive api.